# PyRFC: Connect via mshost (not ashost)

Tags: python, abap, saprfc, pyrfc

I would like to use [PyRFC](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC) to do remote procedure call on SAP using the Python programming language.

```
conn = pyrfc.Connection(user='foouser', passwd='xxxx',
    mshost='sap.example.com', sysid='TE1', client='220',
    group='EXAMPLE',
    )
```

But it fails like this:

```
RFC_COMMUNICATION_FAILURE (rc=1): key=RFC_COMMUNICATION_FAILURE, message=
ERROR       service 'sapmsTE1' unknown
TIME        Tue Dec 18 15:49:40 2018
RELEASE     753
COMPONENT   NI (network interface)
VERSION     40
RC          -3
MODULE      /bas/753_REL/src/base/ni/niuxi.c
LINE        1833
DETAIL      NiPGetServByName: 'sapmsTE1' not found
SYSTEM CALL getaddrinfo
COUNTER     1
 [MSG: class=, type=, number=, v1-4:=;;;]
```

What's wrong?

I guess `sapmsTE1` gets looked up in `/etc/services`. But this file is the default (unmodified) file of my linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. You need to supply the parameter "msserv". AFAIK this is a constant value. This worked:

```
conn = pyrfc.Connection(user='foouser', passwd='xxxx',
    mshost='sap.example.com', sysid='TE1', client='220',
    msserv='3600',
    group='EXAMPLE',
    )
```

Comment: msserv can be different from 3600, it depends on your SAP configuration. Message server ports can be 3600-3699. It is defined in the OS services.

Comment: @SandraRossi  If I am connected via SAP-GUI, how can I see the correct port number which I need to use in the RFC-connection to access the same SAP system?

Comment: You have to ask the SAP administrator. I can't tell you more. Maybe you could ask a question more technically-oriented like "how to know the port of the SAP message server".

Comment: @SandraRossi yes, you are right. I opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847912/sap-port-number-for-msserv-rfc