# Correct message server port (msserv)?

Tags: abap, saprfc, pyrfc

How to determine the correct port for the msserv connection parameter?

According to the docs of [RfcOpenConnection](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwpi711/7.1.1/en-US/48/b0ff6b792d356be10000000a421937/frameset.htm) :

> msserv is only needed, if the service of the message server is not defined as sapms in /etc/services.

In my case I run a standard linux distribution with unmodified `/etc/services` file.

This means I need the matching value for `msserv`.

On one system I was lucky I tried `3600` and it worked.

But on a second system this failed.

I can connect to the system via SAP-GUI.

How to determine the needed value for `msserv`?

This is follow-up of this question: [PyRFC: Connect via mshost (not ashost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835695/pyrfc-connect-via-mshost-not-ashost)

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain, but this should be port 3600+System Number. So for system number 0, you need to connect to port 3600. For system number 01, connect to 3601 and so forth.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek in my case 3600+sysnr is not correct. I can connect using ashost and sysnr (I use the abbreviations according to the first link in the question). But I would like to connect via mshost (Logon with load balancing). In my case sysnr is 90 and msserv is 3630. This means to me, that this question is still looking for an answer.

Comment: the mshost is running on the SCS / ASCS instance of the system and the port would be again 3600 + system number (of the central instance, not the dialog instance). Your dialog instance would in this case be installed as instance number 90, but the central instance would be instance 30. But your admin should be able to give you that information. I'm not sure how you would be able to somehow guess it, unless you start a portscan on those machines over the whole range 3600-3699.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek where does the admin take this information from?

Comment: someone has to install the systems, they don't appear out of thin air. The instance numbers are determined during installation and usually aren't changed after that, although in theory possible.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek I guess the port number is stored in several places. On paper, in the brain of several people, in some /etc/services files and in some canonical place where it is actually used. Where is this place and how to reveal the magic?

Comment: the port/instance number is part of the connection details for a system. The person giving you the IP address or the hostname should also be able to give you this information. Someone in that company has to maintain the SAP GUI connection settings, unless they expect their employees to guess those as well. I'm guessing you don't have direct contact to their SAP basis team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ask the SAP system administrator for telling you the message server service port number. It is specified when installing the SAP system or can be changed and configured later by the system administrator.

If you already have access to the system via SAP GUI and you also have the required authorizations, you can also lookup this in the Message Server Monitor (transaction SMMS in the header area or via menu Goto -> Parameters -> Display) - or you can look into the message server trace file `dev_ms` via transaction ST11, if you have this authorization.

See https://help.sap.com/viewer/ports for a list of port numbers used by SAP software.
The SAP message server service port number was limited to the range 3600-3699 only with old SAP system releases. Nowadays, the SAP message server service port number can be configured freely to any port number (of course not conflicting with other port numbers used by SAP software).

If you do not specify the `msserv` logon parameter, the various [SAP Connectors](https://support.sap.com/connectors) will automatically construct the message server service name via template `sapms<SID>` (e.g. `sapmsTE1`)and then resolve this symbolic service name to the TCP port number afterwards (usually achieved by looking this up from the local file `etc/services`).
By the way, parameter `msserv` may contain the port number *or* the symbolic service name. This is the same as with parameter `gwserv` for the SAP gateway service.

Answer (score 1):

@dirk-trilsbeek is correct. You can find all ports that SAP products use here: https://cp.hana.ondemand.com/dps/d/preview/47673f06bd494db680ff6150c0b08108/2.0/en-US/frameset.htm

Depending on how the application server is installed your port will fall in the 32xx, 33xx or 36xx range, where xx is the instance number that you can find in SAPGui. I do not know an easy way to find the actual port used, but with this information you only need to check 3 to make it work for your RFC calls.

Comment: Thank you for providing a link to the general documentation. My question is slightly different. In want to know the particular port if I use access to mshost (load balancing enabled) instead of ashost (direct application sever) on my system.